# View doesn't update after changing constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I want to change the relation of a constraint programmatically that is why I create a new one and replace the old one with it. I have an IBOutlet of my constraint which I want to change. As because I am using multi-os-engine my code for updating the constraint looks a little bit different to normal objectiv-c or swift.

```
setBasketTopConstraint(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintWithItemAttributeRelatedByToItemAttributeMultiplierConstant(
            basketTopConstraint().firstItem(),
            basketTopConstraint().firstAttribute(),
            NSLayoutRelation.LessThanOrEqual,
            basketTopConstraint().secondItem(),
            basketTopConstraint().secondAttribute(),
            basketTopConstraint().multiplier(),
            basketTopConstraint().constant()
    )
);
```

My problem is, that I can't see any effect from changing the constraint. It seems like I need to refresh my view somehow. I called `view().setNeedsLayout()` and `view().layoutIfNeeded()` but with no success.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you setting the constraint to `active`?

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't change anything. I set it active directly after my code above.

Comment: Then please edit your question to show all of the relevant code.

Comment: @Paulw11 I didn't do this initially. I just tried it now, because you mentioned this. But it does not work for me. So no need to edit my initial question.

Comment: You still don't have enough code to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Well what I do in my code is all I do to change my constraints. I thought maybe I need to do it differently or call some view-update stuff afterwards. I can't rebuild  a whole minimal example. Especially with multi-os-engine which almost no one uses. It was more a general question.

Comment: I understand that, but unfortunately it is basically impossible for us to help,with the code shown. It is known that adding and removing constraints and calling `layoutIfNeeded` *works*, so your code isn't doing something right. If you are changing the relation then you need to remove (or inactivate) the old constraint before adding (and activating) the new constraint. You haven't shown that code

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you. That was the information I needed. I didn't know that I need to deactivate the old one. Now it works. Please feel free to write an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you:

1. Install any new constraints and activate them
2. Deactivate and/or remove any old constraints
3. Call `layoutIfNeeded()`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the code to change constraints in view will layout subviews??

Comment: I want to change the constraint when the keyboard shows, so I got it in a method that gets called when keyboard gets visible.